# Gulp compile less files and minify them

Tags: gulp

I'm new in the use of task runners like Gulp or Grunt, I have chosen to use Gulp to automate my tasks because I'm familiar with Javascript language.

I succeeded to compile my .less files to .css, I even wrote a task to minify my .css files.

I would like to run watch task with BrowSync, which automatically compile .less files to .css and .css to .min.css.

Here's my code :

```
gulp.task('minifyCSS', () => {
return gulp.src([
    'web/assets/css/*.css',
    '!web/assets/css/*.min.css'
])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/assets/css'));});

gulp.task('less', () => {
return gulp.src('web/assets/less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));});
```

`gulp.task('watchSync', ['less', 'minifyCSS', 'browserSync'] , () => {
   gulp.watch('web/assets/less/*.less', ['less']);
});`

```
gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    browser: "chrome",
    proxy: "localhost/web/app_dev.php",
    open: false
});});
```

The browserSync task runs well but it never compiles .css to .min.css. But when I run "gulp minifyCSS" it does the job ...

Do I miss a step ? Can anyone help me on this one ? :)

Comment: are you sure gulp.watch doesn't need a `return` ?

Comment: I'm not sure ... I know that gulp.watch does the job without return but it doesn't go through minifyCSS task :/

Comment: your gulp.watch should call minifyCss not 'less' rule, and the minifyCss rule should require 'less'.

Comment: I see what you mean ! I'm gonna to try it ;)

Comment: It doesn't work my .css is modified but .min.css doesn't change ... I call watchSync this task require 'minifyCss' and the minifyCss rule require 'less'

I will try to find right way to execute tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nearly sure this will work:

```
gulp.task('minifyCSS', ['less'], () => {
  return gulp.src([
        'web/assets/css/*.css',
        '!web/assets/css/*.min.css'
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }))
   ;
});

gulp.task('less', () => {
  return gulp.src('web/assets/less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/assets/css'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('watchSync', ['minifyCSS', 'browserSync'] , () => {
  gulp.watch('web/assets/less/*.less', ['minifyCSS']);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
  browserSync.init({
      notify: false,
      browser: "chrome",
      proxy: "localhost/web/app_dev.php",
      open: false
  });
});
```

Comment: It works ! My mystake was  what task is required ... As you said ! :)

Thank you for your time !